# how to assign keys and values to a dictionary using loops in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, runtime-error

MY CODE:

```
a = ['name1 2 3 4', 'name2 5 6 7']
dicto = {}
i = 0
while (i < 2):
    dicto[a[i][:(a[i].find(''))]] = a[i][a[i].find('') + 1:]
    i += 1
print(dicto)
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
{'name1':'2 3 4','name2':'5,6,7'}
```

MY OUTPUT:

```
{'': 'ame2 5 6 7'}
```

Comment: You are searching for an empty string (`''`), but you should be searching for space (`' '`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dict constructor with the following generator expression with `str.split()`:

```
dict(s.split(maxsplit=1) for s in a)
```

This returns:

```
{'name1': '2 3 4', 'name2': '5 6 7'}
```

Comment: ohh thanks!but im just getting into python,i dont know what a dict constructor is.

Comment: This is using a sequence of key-value tuples to construct a dict with the `dict()` constructor. You can refer to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) of dict constructor for details.

Answer (score 0):

If we use `.split()` on each sublist of `a`  we will get

`a = [['name1', '2', '3', '4'], ['name2', '5', '6', '7']]`

Now we can decide to use the `0` index of the `.split()` being `name` as our `key` and the remaining slice `[1:]` as our values.  To do this we can use a traditional loop

```
dicta = {}
for i in a:
    dicta[i.split()[0]] = i.split()[1:]
# {'name1': ['2', '3', '4'], 'name2': ['5', '6', '7']}
```

This can be shortened using *dictionary comprehension*

```
dicta = {i.split()[0]: i.split()[1:] for i in a}
```

Comment: you are splitting twice, looks dirty

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary comprehension with sequence unpacking:

```
a = ['name1 2 3 4', 'name2 5 6 7']

res = {k: ' '.join(v) for k, *v in map(str.split, a)}

print(res)

{'name1': '2 3 4', 'name2': '5 6 7'}
```